# Cantor's intersection theorem examples

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

> $\bullet \,$Give an example of a sequence $(F_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$
>   of closed sets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $F_1 \supset F_2 \supset F_3
>  \supset \dots$ and $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty F_n = \emptyset.$
>
> $\bullet \,$ Give an example of a decreasing sequence $(F_n)_{n \in
>  \mathbb{N}}$ of closed sets of $\mathbb{Q}$ with $\text{diam} \, F_n
>  \rightarrow 0$ and $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty F_n = \emptyset$

For the first one, I can only think of an example of this type:

$$
F_n = \left[\frac{1}{2^n}, \frac34-\frac{1}{2^n}\right], \, n>1.
$$

but it seems to me that $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty F_n = \frac12 \neq \emptyset.$

I find it hard to think of an example where this intersection is actually empty. Any hints?

Comment: For the first question, try $\bigcap_{n\in \Bbb N} \{x\mid x\ge n \}$. For the second question, try $\bigcap_{n\in \Bbb N} \left([\sqrt 2-1/n, \sqrt 2+1/x]\cap \Bbb Q\right)$

Comment: $\sqrt 2+1/x $ --> $\sqrt 2 +1/n$

Answer (score 2):

You can find clues in the **nested interval theorem** about how to construct counterexamples. The theorem says *nested intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ with their lengths tending to 0 contains one and only one element in $\mathbb{R}$*. Hence

Case (1): You have to make each $F_n$ unbounded, otherwise by the theorem they have a nonempty intersection.

Case (2): Suppose $F_n=[a_n,b_n]$ are nested intervals with $0\leq(b_n-a_n)\to 0$. Then
$$a_n\nearrow a,\ b_n\searrow b$$
Verify that $a=b$ is the only point in the intersection. For this to be empty in $\mathbb{Q}$, you only have to choose $a=b\notin\mathbb{Q}$ and two sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $a_n\nearrow a,\ b_n\searrow a$.

Answer (score 1):

- Consider $F_n=[n,\infty)$
- Fix an irrational number $q\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ and consider $F_n=[q-\frac{1}{n},q+\frac{1}{n}]\cap\mathbb{Q}$